# How to make validation rule for files in custom rule?

Tags: laravel

i am trying to modulate my rule of

```
'files.*' => [
    'file',
    'max:5120',
]
```

so I made `php artisan make:rule File`

and first thing I did was to check if File is an array and not empty

but now I am stuck at this part where I verify every file size and type as 'file'

how do I translate the 'file' and 'max:5120' in my foreach of

```
public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void {
   foreach ($value as $file) {
      // Verifying File Here
   }
}
```

or is there a better way to handle it?